# Background doesn't work on real iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I discovered, that an app can perform background tasks perfectly on the simulator (iOS 9.1) but doesn't do anything in the background on a real iPhone (iOS 9.0.2).
Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?

EDIT: My new Question is: Can an iPhone run processes in the Background without using Background Modes?

Comment: No one can help if you don't provide relevant details such as appropriate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't enable background mode for your application by adding key in plist, then it will not work on real device but will work on simulator.

**For answer of your new question :** 
iPhone can not perform any process in background without using Background Modes.
Also you have to handle background mode properly.

Comment: Okay, that was all I wanted to know.